# Beginner scripting: ^@ appearing at the end of text

Tags: vim

I'm trying to create a script that helps creating shebangs (Ok, it may not be that useful but has advantages when you don't know where the program is, for example), here's what I have so far:

```
function! CreateShebang()
    call inputsave()
    let program = input('Enter the program name: ')
    call inputrestore()
    let path = system('which ' . program)
    call append(0, '#!' . path)
endfunction
```

By the way, I'm just starting with vim scrips, so if you notice any wrong function and concepts or know a better way to achieve the result, please tell me. Any help is really appreciated.

The big problem is that after running, the scripts prompts for the program name correctly and then add something like this to the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl^@
```

What's that `^@` doing there?

Also, If I may ask another question here, how can I clear the command line after `input()`? The text entered by the user keeps showing until another command is entered.

Comment: Answer to another question (it is offtopic, so using comment): try `redraw` or, if it does not help `redraw!`. Note that I used to write it after `input()`, but gave it up because of some issues which I can't remember now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^@` at the end of command is a newline translated to NULL by `append()` function, see `:h NL-used-for-Nul` (it the reason why your `substitute(...\%d000...)` worked while you don't have NULL in your string). As `which` command always outputs newline at the end of string, I suggest you to slightly modify your code by adding `[:-2]` to the end of the `system()` call. This construction will strip just the last byte of function output:

```
let path = system('which ' . program)[:-2]
```

If you use substitute, use

```
let path=substitute(path, '\n', '', 'g')
```

, don't confuse yourself with \%d000 which is semantically wrong.

Comment: Thanks ZyX for the explanations and the redraw tip. Everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Probably the `which` command output contains the NULL character.</s>

The `system()` function replaces line breaks with `<NL>`s. (from `:help system()`). Therefore you could do:

```
let path = substitute(system('which ' . program), '\%x00', '', 'g')
```

Otherwise you could do the following:

```
function! CreateShebang()
    call inputsave()
    0 put = '#!/usr/bin/env ' . input('Enter the program name: ')
    call inputrestore()
endfunction
```

Comment: @Benoit, much of the flexibility this script is intended to have comes from `which`, not always the path will be the same. But your tip that it was a null character helped me in solving this, by simply calling `substitute(path, "\\%d000", "", "")`. May not be the best solution, but works for now. About clearing the command line, I think I'll stick with `echo` (that way, no arguments). Thanks Benoit

Comment: @Benoit, Please ignore my latest comment on `which` usage part. Haven't noticed your clever '/usr/bin/env' right.

Comment: -1: You are wrong: system function cannot replace line breaks with NULLs because it is not possible to have NULLs in a C string (see the last note at `:h expr-string`). Replacement is done by `append()` function, see `:h NL-used-for-Nul`. General idea: in functions/commands that can take/return a list of lines NL represents NULL and list items are considered to be separated by NL. What is mentioned in `:h system()` is only replacing line endings on different systems, you can check `:echo string(system('echo -e ''a\0b'''))`: it will echo a single `a`.

Comment: By the way, `\x00` in a pattern means hex digit followed by two zeroes.

Comment: @ZyX: You're right, the correct expression is `\%x00`. I have tested it. system('which which.exe') will have trailing newline, whereas sustituting `\%x00` removes it.

Comment: @Benoit Explanation why `\%x00` removes it is given in my answer. **There is no NULL in system output.** Check any command that outputs real NULL, string that is output by `system()` function won't extend after first NULL outputted by command. Try adding a NULL to a string and it will be truncated. **There is no NULL in any vim string.** It is just impossible. References are given in my first comment.

Comment: @Benoit I strongly suggest never write `\%x00` because `\n` is shorter and `\n` is what is actually stored in the string, so using `\%x00` will confuse other people who doesn't know VimL enough and thus may think that you search for NULL byte.