# Avoiding ^@ when appending multiline text in Vimscript

Tags: vim

I yanked some text in my script and stored it in a variable, for instance:

```
line_1
line_2
line_3
line_4
```

then later I want to append that text into the current buffer, so I run this:

```
append(line("."),myvariable)
```

but the pasted text has weird character where every end of line should be:

```
line_1^@line_2^@line_3^@line_4
```

How can I avoid this and get them pasted correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Useful [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105500/beginner-scripting-appearing-at-the-end-of-text?rq=1)

---

To remove the `^@`, you can use substitute :

```
let myvariable=substitute(myvariable, '\n', '', 'g')
```

but then everything will be on one line.

Comment: That explains how it gets translated, but what about appending it avoiding that translation?  (I didn't call strtrans)